# SQL order by creation time ASC

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    p.[TerminalId],
    Keys = JSON_QUERY('[' + string_agg(json_query('{"Point":"' + p.Location.STAsText() + '","CreatedDateTime":"' + cast(p.CreatedDateTime as nvarchar(20)) + '"}'),',') + ']')
FROM
    (SELECT
         geography::STGeomFromText(Location.STAsText(), 4326) as Location,
         [CreatedDateTime],
         [TerminalId],
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [CreatedDateTime] ASC) AS RowNum
     FROM 
         [Magicar_Route].[dbo].[PacketLocations]) AS p
GROUP BY 
    p.[TerminalId]
```

I want `p.Location` sorted by `CreatedDateTime asc` in `Keys` JSON column but after query `Location` not sorted `ASC`?

How could I sort my location according **CreatedDateTime  ASC**?

I changed my query to this:

```
WITH NewScores AS 
(
    SELECT
        geography::STGeomFromText(Location.STAsText(), 4326) AS Location,
        [CreatedDateTime],
        [TerminalId]
    FROM
        [Magicar_Route].[dbo].[PacketLocations]
    ORDER BY 
        [CreatedDateTime] ASC
)
SELECT 
    [TerminalId],
    Keys = JSON_QUERY('['+ string_agg(json_query('{"Point":"' + Location.STAsText() + '","CreatedDateTime":"' + cast(CreatedDateTime as nvarchar(20)) + '"}'),',') + ']')
FROM
    NewScores
```

But unfortunately I got this error:

> Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 100
>   The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: Do you have sample data you can share? As the message states you can't have the order by in the CTE, but I'm sure there is another way to do what you want.

Comment: Sample data and expected result will help provide a working solution. Please [edit] your question with [proper sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the order by inside the CTE, put it for the query below

```
WITH NewScores AS 
(
    SELECT
        geography::STGeomFromText(Location.STAsText(), 4326) AS Location,
        [CreatedDateTime],
        [TerminalId]
    FROM
        [Magicar_Route].[dbo].[PacketLocations]
)
SELECT 
    [TerminalId],
    Keys = JSON_QUERY('['+ string_agg(json_query('{"Point":"' + Location.STAsText() + '","CreatedDateTime":"' + cast(CreatedDateTime as nvarchar(20)) + '"}'),',') + ']')
FROM
    NewScores
ORDER BY 
    [CreatedDateTime] ASC
```

Comment: I got this error `Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 123
Column 'NewScores.TerminalId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` @Srinika Pinnaduwage

Comment: try order by min([CreatedDateTime])